# AJAX Fill Dropdown based on Dropdown Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Im wondering what's wrong with my script, it's not getting the values of cities based on country, please see my code:

Controller: Hotel

```
private ActionResult FillCity(int countryid)
{
    var cities = db.cities.Where(c => c.country_id == countryid);
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Jquery/AJAX

```
<script>
    function FillCity() {
        var countryid = $('#Country').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FillCity")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { countryid: countryid },
            success: function (cities) {
                $("#City").html(""); 
                $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                    $("#City").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(city.id).html(city.name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

View

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "id", "country_name"), "Select Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillCity()" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "id", "name"), "Select City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im checking the console it seems the url is correct [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method is marked as private so it will never be hit. Change it to

```
public ActionResult FillCity(int countryid)
{
    var cities = db.cities.Where(c => c.country_id == countryid).Select(c => new
    {
        id = c.id,
        name = c.name
    };
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Side note: If typeof `City` contains more than the `id` and `name` properties you need to generate the options (it does because it contains at least `country_id`), you should modify the query to return a collection of anonymous objects containing only those properties you need in the view

Comment: thanks, now its hitting it, but not getting any values in cities dropdown

Comment: Are you properties named `id` and `name` (exact case)?

Comment: @Nevi use debugger and check whether you are getting any data in `cities` or not

Comment: There is nothing you have shown in your code that suggests what the problem is. I have solved your question and so you really need to debug your code first - does `cities` contain the values you expect? (and if your still having problems, ask a new question). But your do have other problems with you code, including that if you return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, all the values of the second dropdownlist will be empty. I suggest you look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JofdB8) for the correct way to handle this

Comment: im pretty sure cities does have value @JSantosh

Comment: @StephenMuecke i browse http://localhost:49827/Hotel/FillCity?countryid=2 i get this error There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Comment: See edit (and if you are still getting the same error, then try `return Json(cities.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: But you have other problems as well If the user selects a country and then selects the first ("Select Country") option, the value of `countryid` will be `null` and you will get an error. (you need to check for `null` before calling the controller)

Comment: you are using ADO.net approach to load data ? if yes then you forgot write the code for closing the DataReader connection that is opened for reading the data.

Comment: i tried the edited code i got The entity or complex type 'AdminMvc.city' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: it works now, i changed my query 

    var cities = from c in db.cities where c.country.id == Country select new { id = c.id, name = c.name}; 
            return Json(cities.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);